# Updated Path after installing flutter for first time however command prompt is not able to show flutter comments

Tags: flutter, command, prompt

I have installed flutter for the first time in my PC, I have extracted all the files and saved in SRC folder. After adding the Full path of BIN folder to the existing path by the separator (;), I noticed that command prompt is showing some error when I was trying to check whether flutter can be run by command prompt. Here is the error I encountered:

> 'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file

I am trying to look for the flutter version. What can I do to fix this error?

I also have updated the path correctly as `C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin`.

Comment: where did you download/place your flutter files?

Comment: @Uni   extracted my flutter files and placed in C:\src\flutter as mentioned in Flutter website. I downloaded it and extrated files and then as mentioned i edited my path directory and when i checked command prompt for flutter version to verify if i can use flutter from anywhere, i got the error as 'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. i have I3 processor HP laptop

Comment: Check this out. I'm pretty sure something went wrong with adding it to the path enviroment inside user's variables. https://enappd.com/blog/setup-flutter-in-windows-and-mac/36/